# Overriding template default.phtml not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

In my custom module I have the file `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` 
with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>     
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />            
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />  
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But its not working

this is my core file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Remove checkout.cart.item.renderers.override. It should be checkout.cart.item.renderers. Remove cache or delete var/* and check.

Comment: still not working

Comment: It is working for me, can you please check file location (MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml) and don't forget to clear cache or remove var/* .

Comment: still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code (replace with your code). Don't forget to remove/clear cache.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: yes Working.But why we go for this format

Comment: If we don't use its child block then it will not consider our template and take theme default.phtml file. Please accept above answer if its helpful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking what you are trying to do, I think a better & easier approach could be just overriding the template **Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml** in your module, doesn't it?

Comment: yes............